Need to GET OAuth Token with just client id and no client secret and redirect url
I have configured an API and my client can only to pass client_id to get OAuth token back as a response. He can't pass client secret and no redirect_url. I tried with Implicit type and I see the below redirect url. can anyone help?
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Redirect URI specified in the request is not configured in the client subscription"
}

Is there any alternative way?


Note that: Implicit grant flow requires redirect URL as a parameter. Refer this MsDoc

If you don't want to pass client secret and redirect URL in the request, then you can make use of ROPC flow or Device code flow

ROPC flow has limitations and is not recommended by Microsoft due to security issues.
It doesn't support personal Microsoft accounts and accounts enabled with MFA.
ROPC flow is not secure as you will be passing username and password in the request directly and with no client secret.

Hence, to generate access token by passing ClientID only, enable  Allow public client flows as YES

And pass the below request:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=ClientID
grant_type=password
username=UserName
password=Password
scope=user.read openid offline_access profile



Otherwise, you can also make use of Device authorization request like below:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode

client_id=ClientID
scope=user.read

This will generate a verification_uri and a user_code:

Now click on the verification_uri in the browser and enter the code:
That is paste this URL in broswerhttps://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter code

And sign-in to authenticate:

Generate the access token by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code
client_id:ClientID
device_code:DeviceCodeFromAboveRequest


